# removing duplicate checkboxes from a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a form that's generated and sent back by mvc and razor, how would I remove the dupicates from the form? eg. there are two checkboxes with grapes and one with bananas, I'd wanna remove the duplicate grapes one. I could put $('.fruit') into an array, but how would I target the duplicates from there?

```
 <div class="fruit">
      <input data-val="true" data-val-number="" data-val-required="" name=" [5].UniqueValue[3].Id" type="hidden" value="123">
      <input name="[5].UniqueValue[3].fruit" type="hidden" value=".grapes">
      <input data-val="" data-val-required="" name="[5].UniqueValue[3].IsSelected" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="[5].UniqueValue[3].IsSelected" type="hidden" value="false"> grapes
 </div>
 <div class="fruit">
      <input data-val="true" data-val-number="" data-val-required="" name="[5].UniqueValue[2].Id" type="hidden" value="321">
      <input name="[5].UniqueValue[2].fruit" type="hidden" value=".bananas">
      <input data-val="" data-val-required="" name="[5].UniqueValue[2].IsSelected" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="[5].UniqueValue[2].IsSelected" type="hidden" value="false"> bananas
 </div>
 <div class="fruit">
      <input data-val="true" data-val-number="" data-val-required="" name="[5].UniqueValue[1].Id" type="hidden" value="456">
      <input name="[5].UniqueValue[1].fruit" type="hidden" value=".grapes">
      <input data-val="" data-val-required="" name="[5].UniqueValue[1].IsSelected" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="[5].UniqueValue[1].IsSelected" type="hidden" value="false"> grapes
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`:gt()`](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) and the [`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selectors.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3tapw/2/)

```
$('.fruit > [name$=fruit]').each(function () {
    $('.fruit:has([value="' + $(this).prop('value') + '"]):gt(0)').remove();
});
```

Comment: @archytect Fixed, I changed `value=val` for `value="val"`, its safer.

Comment: @archytect I'm glad to hear this!

Comment: hey plalx, one more question, what If it was simplified to just have the word and didn't have any input fields? http://jsfiddle.net/3tapw/4/